# Saving HTML5 canvas data to server

Tags: php, ajax, html, canvas

I know there is a lot of questions regarding this but currently I am trying to save user created HTML5 canvas data to a specific folder on my web server.

I am already able to save an image to server using the following:

```
function sendData(postData){
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("POST",'saveFrame.php',true);
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'canvas/upload');

var comicID = document.getElementById('comicID').value;

ajax.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (ajax.readyState == 4)
    {
        alert("Frame saved");
    }
}
ajax.send(postData);
}
```

saveFrame.PHP File

```
<?php

if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{
    // Get the data like you would with traditional post
    $rawImage=$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];

    // Remove the headers  
    $removeHeaders=substr($rawImage, strpos($rawImage, ",")+1);

    // decode it from base 64 and into image data only
    $decode=base64_decode($removeHeaders);

    // save to your server
    $saveName = "test.jpeg";
    $fopen = fopen($saveName, 'wb' );
    fwrite( $fopen, $decode);
    fclose( $fopen );
}
?>
```

What I want to be able to do is pass some more variables along side the image so that I can dynamically look up my database using PHP within the saveFrame.php file to determine what filename it should be saved as.  I'm unsure how to accomplish this as I'm not accustomed to using AJAX.

Any advice is appreciated,

Alex

Comment: Were you able to save the canvas and render it successfully back?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the html5 `canvaspixelarray` property to obtain the canvas data.